# Elasticsearch optional maven depdendencies

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using Elasticsearch 2.1. When I start up the system, I get several exceptions about failing to load classes related to scripting. For example,

```
failed to load mustache
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.mustachejava.Mustache
```

I can resolve this problem by including these dependencies in my project, but I am not using these scripting languages. Is there a way to tell Elasticsearch to disable their use and to prevent it from throwing the exceptions?

Comment: It's worth noting that the exceptions are logged by Elasticsearch at a debug level, so changing the logging level would prevent them from appearing in logs. That said, if Elasticsearch is intended to be able to run without these dependencies, it should behave in a more reasonable manner when they do not exist.

Comment: Can you share your pom file and the code that you're using?